# How to add to the k+1th element of numpy array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

In Matlab, I have this code:

```
h{1} = zeros(16,16);
for i = 1:9
    for j = 1:13
        h{1}(i+3,j+1) = ht1(i,j);
    end
end

for k=1:11
    ag = 15*k;
    h{k+1} = imrotate(h{1},ag,'bicubic');
end
```

But I'm having a hard time porting it to Python, here's what I've tried:

```
h= np.zeros((16,16))
for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 13):
        h[i+3, j+1] = ht1[i, j]

h = [scipy.misc.imrotate(h, 15*i, 'bicubic') for i in range(0, 11)]
```

But I know for sure that the line:

```
h = [scipy.misc.imrotate(h, 15*i, 'bicubic') for i in range(0, 11)]
```

from the above code is overriding the numpy array that I create and add elements to before that. How do I do as done in the Matlab code?

Comment: Why did you convert the for loop into list comprehension?

Comment: I know, that's the part that is wrong. Just ignore it. That part is my question. How do I add to the k+1th element instead of turning it into a list.

Comment: I think `h` needs to initially be a `list` and set the first element to `np.zeros((16,16))`, then you can `.extend` by the comprehension?

Comment: Does the Matlab code "add to `k+1`". It looks like it makes a new matrix in the cell array of `h` at the index of `k+1`

Comment: I just tried doing that, and I got index out of range for `h = []`, 
  `h[0] = np.zeros((16,16))`

Comment: If you are doing that, then use `h.add(np.zeros((16, 16))`

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, that's exactly what it does. How can I do that in Python?

Comment: The Matlab code is creating a cell array (that's what the `{}` notation is for) of matrices. The Python code you've created does very much the same thing (Python lists are almost like Matlab cell arrays), except perhaps that you should be using `range(12)` in the list comprehension.

Comment: But my list comprehension is overwriting the array of zeros that I create before that

Comment: But the list you are getting out (`h`) contains all the correct images. `h[0]` is still the unrotated one, and the rest are all what you expect as well. I've posted a more literal translation as an answer, but I don't think there is anything wrong with your code as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is nothing wrong in what your code creates, the final result is a list of arrays just like the Matlab code was creating a cell array of matrices.

If you want a more literal translation, you can try this:

```
h = [np.zeros((16,16))]  # this creates h as a one element list
for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 13):
        h[0][i+3, j+1] = ht1[i, j]  # now we index a lot like before

for i in range(1, 12):
    h.append(scipy.misc.imrotate(h[0], 15*i, 'bicubic')
```

Just to be clear, I will repeat that you are obtaining the correct result with your original code, even though you are re-using the name `h` for the final result. Since rotation by 0 degrees gives the same image, you are not losing anything.

Answer (score 0):

A Python equivalent of a Matlab cell array could be either be a Python dictionary or a list, so you'll need one of those instead of just a single `h` variable that holds a matrix.

This example uses a list.

```
h = [ np.zeros((16,16)) ]
for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 13):
        h[0][i+3, j+1] = ht1[i, j] # not sure what 'ht1' is here... 

h.extend(scipy.misc.imrotate(h[0], 15*i, 'bicubic')  for i in range(1, 12))
```

Also, note that Python ranges are non-inclusive on the end and that `range(0, x)` can be simplified to just `range(x)`

Comment: This contains the zero rotation image twice.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Not sure I follow. I just translated to the best of my ability.

Comment: In the Matlab version, the first element of `h` is the unrotated image. The others are all rotated by a nonzero angle (`for i = 1:12` starts at 1).

Comment: Do you mean h.append(np.zeros((16,16))?

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I think I see what you mean based on the `15*i`value. @stack Yes, I did